# Firebase server responding very slow and terminating connection with status canceled

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

We are an education company and provide online education to the student all over the world. The students come to our portal and ask live questions.

When they come, we connect them to Firebase through the custom token.

Before It was working fine but now it's failing to connect and terminating the connection with status **canceled**.

Library Versions:

- AngularJS v1.4.5
- Firebase v2.4.2

**And Student strength is ~8-10K at the same time.**

We are using Firebase "**pay as you go**" payment.

Now we shifted with new Firebase database and it's working normally without any issue.

But I wanted to why it failed before with old database.

See below screenshot.

[image]